# Any tips to avoid laggy display during long kernels?

Tags: cuda, lag

Dear CUDA users I am reposting a question from nvidia boards:
I am currently doing image processing on GPU and I have one kernel that takes something like 500 to 700 milliseconds when running on big images. It used to work perfectly on smaller images but now the problem is that **the whole display and even the mouse cursor are getting laggy** (OS=win7)

My idea was to **split my kernel** in 4 or 8 kernel launches, hoping that the driver could refresh more often (between each kernel launch).
Unfortunately it does not help at all, so what else could I try to avoid this freezing display effect? I was suggested to add a `cudaStreamQuery(0)` call between each kernel to avoid packing by the driver.

Note: I am prepared to trade performances for smoothness!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GPU is not (yet) designed to context switch between kernel launches, which is why your long-running kernel is causing a laggy display. Breaking the kernel into multiple launches probably would help on platforms other than Windows Vista/Windows 7.  On those platforms, the Windows Display Driver Model requires an expensive user->kernel transition ("kernel thunk") every time the CUDA driver wants to submit work to the GPU.

To amortize the cost of the kernel thunk, the CUDA driver queues up GPU commands and submits them in batches.  The driver uses a heuristic to trade off the performance hit from the kernel thunk against the increased latency of not immediately submitting work. What's happening with your multiple-kernels solution is that the driver's submitting your kernel or series of kernels to the GPU all at once.

Have you tried the cudaStreamQuery(0) suggestion?  The reason that might help is because it *forces* the CUDA driver to submit work to the GPU, even if very little work is pending.

Comment: I finally broke my kernel into 16 launches in a smarter way and added the required `cudaStreamQuery(0)` between each call. As expected the summed processing time has increased but the display is now correctly refreshed.